# Synchronisation of multiple address mappings on the same DMA buffer

Tags: caching, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, dma

I am writing a simple kernel module that uses the DMA API for external DMAs on an aarch64 system.

My current steps excluding error handling can be summarized as follows:

```c
// get free pages that are aligned to PAGE_SIZE (kmalloc() is not page aligned)
buffer = __get_free_pages(GFP_KERNEL | GFP_DMA, size_in_pages);
// map the buffer for DMA to device
dma_address = dma_map_single(&dma_device, buffer, size_in_byte, DMA_TO_DEVICE);
// after dma_map_single(), the buffer is "owned" by the device, we sync it back so that we can write to it
dma_sync_single_for_cpu(&dma_device, dma_address, size_in_byte, DMA_TO_DEVICE);
```

Later, I remap the physical address to userspace with

```c
remap_pfn_range(vma, vma->vm_start, PFN_DOWN(dma_address) + vma->vm_pgoff, size, vma->vm_page_prot);
```

This might be dangerous (see the questions later). The application modifies the memory.

Afterwards, I call

```c
dma_sync_single_for_device(&dma_device, dma_address, size_in_byte, DMA_FROM_DEVICE);
```

to sync the buffer to the device and trigger the DMA starting from `dma_address`.

Here, I have some questions:

1. `dma_sync_single_for_device()` flushes the cache. Does this also include data that was written by the application by using the virtual userspace mapping done by `remap_pfn_range()`, or only the original mapping `buffer`? If this would be the case, the code should not work.
2. Does `dma_sync_single_for_device()` include all necessary memory barriers?
3. Should I make the virtual mapping uncached with `vma->vm_page_prot = pgprot_noncached(vma->vm_page_prot);`?

Comment: 2. The barriers for what? How does it know HW specifics of the  `dma_device` or generally speaking about device that _uses_ this DMA? That asked, I believe the proper answer here is **no**.

Comment: 1.It flushes the respective (IO)MMU mapping. I believe it doesn't know about anybody who writes to the same memory under different mappings. That said, I think the conclusion is correct, **the code shouldn't work**.

Comment: 3. `UC-` is what usually being used for IO. Not sure what ARM64 needs in such case. And ARM64 IIRC is not cache-coherent, right?

Comment: With barriers I meant CPU barries like explained for the  Consistent DMA mappings  `Consistent DMA memory does not preclude the usage of proper memory barriers.` https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/DMA-API-HOWTO.txt

Comment: Yes, I understood you. What I meant is that barriers are for visibility of the cachelines to other CPUs and/or memory controller. Each barrier should have a pair or at least understanding how it affects the DMA transactions. But all those barriers are completely hardware dependent. What hardware **exactly** (device that _needs_ DMA) do you have in mind?

Comment: Its on SoC with an external DMA device that accesses the same Memory Controller as the Cores, but is not cache coherent to the CPU caches. So my guess is that at least all CPU caches must be cleared.

Comment: For the streaming DMA API, you should be remapping the buffer pages, not the DMA addresses. For consistent DMA API, there are special functions for remapping.

Comment: @IanAbbott you mean using something like `vm_map_pages_zero`?

Comment: You can still use `remap_pfn_ranges` using `virt_to_pfn(buffer)` for the first PFN of the buffer allocated with `__get_free_pages()`. You might need to use the `__GFP_COMP` flag during allocation to make the page reference counting work properly.